# PDF file is only opened with an old version of Foxitreader

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a weird problem with a legacy app I'm trying to support.

From a Java application, I am using JasperReports 6.1.0 to generate a PDF report that I'm opening with FoxitReader v2.0 Build 1606, by just calling

```
"C:/path/to/FoxitReader.exe" + " " + /absolute/path/to/pdf
```

(ok, ugly pseudo code, but you get the point)

The PDF file opens fine and I can read and print the file, see pic: [image]

But:

- If I select "Save file as", and save as a different file name OR
- If I open the generated `/absolute/path/to/pdf` with a newer version of FoxitReader or Adobe Reader

Then the same PDF file opens as:

[image]

The funky pdf file is available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5izDr7AD9lXWFFKNnlNYS04VFU

From the File Properties of the old FoxitReader (that one that works) I get:

```
Creator: JasperReports Library version null 
Producer: iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT
PDF Version: PDF-1.4
```

I have no idea why this file can only be opened by that old FoxitReader.

The only workaround to get my hands on a workable PDF version, is to do a print to PDF, from the old FoxitReader to the pdf print driver of a later version of FoxitReader and use the generated PDF file from the print job, but this is quite a hack.

Any ideas on how to debug this (apart from upgrading everything to latest versions) would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  Added the file in the question body.

Comment: By "Then the same PDF file opens as" you mean the PDF you try to open with the foxit.exe call you're doing? 

Is the provided PDF the original PDF? That no application opened? If not, could you provide us with that one? It's a bit unclear right now which file you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry again if it was not clear.  Yes, the original pdf file, that I shared, is generated once.  It opens fine with the old version of Foxitreader, but newer versions of FoxitReader, or Adobe Reader, both display it in the jumbled form i screenshoted above.